# Bash: Open new tab in newly opened terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-scripting, gnome-terminal

I want to open new terminal windows, each with multiple tabs, and while I've managed to open the windows, I'm having trouble with the tabs. What I currently have is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Opens new window, but with only one tab, code after --tab-with... does not work:
  gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -- bash -ic "command; bash;" --tab-with-profile=Bash -- bash -ic "command; bash;"

# This opens a new tab in the same terminal, not the one I created with the above command:
  ## gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=Bash -- bash -ic "command; bash;"

# Correctly opens a new window:
  gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Bash -- bash -ic "command; bash;"

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since question was still open I assume you haven't found what you wanted, either way it might be useful for future visitors of this post.

Here's how you can do it:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "gnome-terminal --tab; bash"
```

The `bash` at the end makes it so that the window will stay open so you can omit the `-i` option.

If you want to open a window with let's say 5 tabs, you could simply throw in a for loop:

```
// Loop 4 times since opening a window already starts us with 1 tab
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "for i in {1..4}; do gnome-terminal --tab; done; bash"
```